# Check for Specifics words in a Text

Tags: java, android, string

So my Question as i never worked so much with String is :

How can i Check if a Text Contain 1 or More Words ?

Eg. : Word ONE ,
      this is WORD two
      and this is the word THREE

Thanks All .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ignore case you can use regex like

```
String data = "Word ONE , this is WORD two and this is the word THREE, " +
        "(words will not be counted)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bword\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
int counter = 0;
while (m.find())
    System.out.println("[" + counter++ + "]" + m.group());
```

This code will count words `Word` `WORD` and `word` but not `words` (if you want to include `words` change regex to `Pattern.compile("word", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the words you want to check and call [`String.contains`?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: before i used it , or maybe it was Split beacause i was trying to get a specific word in a String , Nevermind its work thx u

Answer (score 0):

**-** You can use String's method `contains()`

**Eg:**

```
String s = "Hello i am good";

if (s.contains("am")){

    // Do what u want
}
```